# Change the default event cell view in FullCalendar jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Maybe is an obvious question but I search on FullCalendar API, SO and google with no results. I wondering if I can change the default cell view of every event into the FullCalendar?

For example my current events cell are only showing the time and the title I parsed from the data object. When I try to parse more data in the object I cannot display them into the calendar cell

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2015-02-01'
        morecontent : 'MORE CONTENT' // How to display this??
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2015-02-07',
        end: '2015-02-10'
        morecontent : 'MORE CONTENT' // and this??
    }
];
```

Comment: How are you saving your events? Are you just pulling from a JSON file or from the database?

Comment: I generate a JSON from database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the cell during the `eventRender`, which is triggered when the event is being rendered ([docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)).

Something like the code below will find the title for that specific event and replace the html with the title + the more content:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $(element).find('.fc-title').html(event.title + ', ' + event.morecontent);
}
```

Here's a working version:

```js
$('#fullCal').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
    title: 'Random Event 1',
    start: moment().add(-4, 'h'),
    end: moment().add(-2, 'h'),
    morecontent: 'Eat Pizza',
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Random Event 2',
    start: moment().add(1, 'd'),
    end: moment().add(2, 'd'),
    morecontent: 'Drink Coffee',
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Random Event 3',
    start: moment().add(6, 'd'),
    end: moment().add(8, 'd'),
    morecontent: 'Hackathon',
    allDay: false
  }],
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'prev title next today',
    right: ''
  },
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $(element).find('.fc-title').html(event.title + ', ' + event.morecontent);
  },
  timezone: 'local'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullCal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like so far, your JSON (from the database) is creating the code you provided above. If so, then whatever its in `morecontent` should already be passed as a result to your fullcalendar object.

To test use:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
     console.log(calEvent);
}
```